# Mikrotik: One firewall rule for multiple chains?

Tags: firewall, mikrotik-routeros

I created multiple firewall rules for input chain as described [in an article](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Drop_port_scanners) and now it seems that I need to create the same set of rules for forward chain. Could I make a rule for multiple chains?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the 'common' rules of both input and forward chains into a new chain and then from the input and forward chain you only need to jump rules to the newly created chain. ie: 1 rule per chain.

This way you maintain a single set of rules for both input and forward chains.